# EntityManager convert 'is' and 'is not' operators to = and <> How to prevent such case?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I have the following hql :

```
SELECT obj FROM com.domain.view.DomainClass obj  WHERE  obj.x  LIKE  :p1 AND  obj.y is not :p2 AND  obj.z = :p3 ORDER BY a DESC
```

while the result from hibernate is:

```
select obj0_.a as a_, obj0_.b as b_ from obj_table obj0_ where (obj0_.x like ?) and obj0_.y<>? and obj0_.z=? order by obj0_.a DESC
```

note that the 'is not' (an also 'is') is converted to <> and = which doesn't work with null values

The query is actually generated from TypedQuery class.
My question is how to prevent JPA/Hibernate entityManager from converting 'is' and 'is not' to = and <>?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to enforce the is and is not on the entity manager

Comment: You might want to add that both to the question as well as the title, right now both are just *statements*.

Comment: Why is this question tagged [tag:mysql]?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot well, this problem happens with mysql only as mysql return false for columnx=null unlike oracle.